# Android MediaPlayer's getDuration() method gets value from metadata rather than actual media length

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm working on an app where users will be able to play their music through the app via a MediaPlayer.

The problem I'm running into is that media files which have been edited by the user give incorrect values when the getDuration() method is called. I did some experimenting and it seems that oftentimes when a user edits a song using an audio editing tool, the metadata (which includes song length) remains unchanged. This results in the media player seeing the song as a 3 minute song hen it is in fact only 30 seconds. This is a big problem because many users will use ringtones or other snippits of songs with the app's media player, which will result in the progress bar and TextView which displays the song's length being incorrect.

Obviously I can't control the kinds of audio editing tools people use prior to using my app. Is there anything I can do on the app-end to give accurate getDuration() values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The modifications done to the media files programmatically will not be reflected in the MediaScanner. So, if necessary you can try rescanning the mediastore when the application starts. Refer https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/cf41cc88b6eb4393.

Comment: The changes to the media files are not made by my program. When someone uses a audio editing tool (such as Audacity, Ringdroid, etc), the metadata contains the original length of the file rather than the length of the new segment. I tried using some of these files in Winamp, and the same problem occurs. Any idea how to re-scan and re-assign a duration metadata tag to a file programmatically?

Comment: Programmatically means not only your program. Any other softwares modifying the song also will not be reflected in the database containing the metadata  unless the MediaScanner is rescanned. Procedure to rescan and update the metadata is there in the link given above.